# Error in installing ncdf on Linux when ever i want to install ncdf package it show this error

Tags: package

> install.packages("ncdf")
>   * installing *source* package ‘ncdf’ ...
>   ** package ‘ncdf’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked checking for nc-config... /usr/local/bin/nc-config configure: creating
>   ./config.status config.status: creating src/Makevars
>   ** libs gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c ncdf.c -o ncdf.o gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include
>   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c ncdf2.c -o ncdf2.o gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG
>   -I/usr/local/include     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c ncdf3.c -o ncdf3.o gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
>   -Wl,-z,relro -o ncdf.so ncdf.o ncdf2.o ncdf3.o -L/usr/local/lib -lnetcdf -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libnetcdf.a(attr.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against
>   `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with
>   -fPIC /usr/local/lib/libnetcdf.a: error adding symbols: Bad value collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [ncdf.so] Error 1
>   ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ncdf’
>   * removing ‘/home/ayesha/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/ncdf’
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
>     '/tmp/RtmpSrzd8P/downloaded_packages'

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Can you tell us what did you try so far?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17028625/707145) might be helpful for you.

Comment: And [here](http://pablomarin-garcia.blogspot.com/2013/05/issues-installing-r-package-ncdf.html) is another link.

Comment: yes it is working . MYaseen208 thank you

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Would recommend you answer your own question.